# FindText, how to use WindowToScreen() helper function with FindText()?

Tags: autohotkey

I have been messing around with **FindText** Library by user **feiyue**, link to library [HERE](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17834), I am stuck on using one of its helper functions, I wonder someone who is familiar with it can help me.

Currently I can find a graphic, the number `4`,  by using the following:

```
#Include <FindText>
F1::
t1:=A_TickCount, Text:=X:=Y:=""
Text:="|<4>**50$6.66CCKqz66U"
if (ok:=FindText(X, Y, 1407-150000, 1196-150000, 1407+150000, 1196+150000, 0, 0, Text))
{
}
MsgBox, 4096, Tip, % "Found:`t" Round(ok.Length())
  . "`n`nTime:`t" (A_TickCount-t1) " ms"
  . "`n`nPos:`t" ok[1].x ", " ok[1].y
  . "`n`nResult:`t<" (Comment:=ok[1].id) ">"
for i,v in ok  ; ok value can be get from ok:=FindText().ok
  if (i<=2)
    FindText().MouseTip(ok[i].x, ok[i].y)
```

But the above uses screen coordinates, so it matches a bunch of other ones all over the my array of monitors, even the target window. its also slow, I have 4 monitors.

I tried a test where I specified a very limited range of coordinates in `if (ok:=FindText(X, Y,,,,, 0, 0, Text))` it was able to find it much faster `10ms`. But using hardcoded coordinates is not ideal as I am constantly moving this window.

Reading the various articles for this library, I found there is a helper function for this exact need, `FindText().WindowToScreen(outX2, outY2, 200, 300)`.
The help I was able to find on the function mentions:

> `FindText().WindowToScreen(outX2, outY2, 200, 300)` If `ahk_id` is not specified, then the active window will be used

my goal is to get the script to **only** look at the active windows body, when searching for a graphic

But I am struggling to actually get a working example using my previous code:

```
#Include <FindText>
F1::
t1:=A_TickCount, Text:=X:=Y:=""
Text:="|<4>**50$6.66CCKqz66U"
;if (ok:=FindText(X, Y, 1407-150000, 1196-150000, 1407+150000, 1196+150000, 0, 0, Text))
;if (ok:=FindText(X, Y, outX2, outY2, 777, 236, 0, 0, Text).WindowToScreen(outX2, outY2, 777, 236))
if (ok:=FindText(outX2,outY2, , , , , 0, 0, Text).WindowToScreen(outX2, outY2, 775, 60))
{
}
MsgBox, 4096, Tip, % "Found:`t" Round(ok.Length())
  . "`n`nTime:`t" (A_TickCount-t1) " ms"
  . "`n`nPos:`t" ok[1].x ", " ok[1].y
  . "`n`nResult:`t<" (Comment:=ok[1].id) ">"
for i,v in ok  ; ok value can be get from ok:=FindText().ok
  if (i<=2)
    FindText().MouseTip(ok[i].x, ok[i].y)
```

The script fails to find the graphic, I have tried a bunch of variations but nothing works.

I am out of ideas here, so any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try it like this instead?
if (ok:=FindText.WindowToScreen(outX2,outY2, , , , , 0, 0, Text)
But no idea if thats how it works and wouldn't it be better if when making images it made them use the window area instead of screen? Seen it used elsewhere like this in this part though.
actually wouldn't you want to use
FindText().ScreenToWindow since you only want it to use window you are in as well?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).